# console output req.params in node/express

Tags: node.js, express

When I do:

`console.log(req.params),` it outputs:

```
[ id: "param1" ]
```

However when I do, `console.log("Params:[%s]", req.params),`it outputs

```
[[]]
```

I also tried

```
 console.log("Params:[%j]", req.params),
 console.log("Params:[%s]", JSON.stringify(req.params)), 
 console.log("Params:" + req.params),
```

with output not as expected.

What is wrong here?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try require('util').inspect() method for formatting. The format for calling that method changed in 0.10.0, so depending on what version of node you are in you will have to use a different node doc.

Here are links to the pre and post 0.10.0 version of the function.

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.25/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.13/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

So, you would do something like:

```
console.log( require('util').inspect( req.params ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because `req.params` isn't actually an object but it's a function. The reason it's a function is so you can do `req.params('name', 'default value')`.

Source: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L283